# The conditions are right. Where's my Mega Stone?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have gotten the Mega Ring upgraded in my Y version, I've battled my rival after 2 rounds in the battle mansion, talked to Professor Sycamore, and waited near the Gyaradosite location between 8:00-9:00. My Mega Stone isn't showing up. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your time set properly in the 3ds? Have you adjusted for Daylight savings time, if applicable to your region?

Comment: it should be set correctly, when i went to go look for them i was going to save and it said 8:08 so im pretty sure the time is set. ive gone online and have looked and tried to figure out what it could be but cant figure out what it could be